# How to make rspec give me me more helpful output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having some tests fail on pretty simple requests that I can validate manually should pass.

```
it { should have_selector('title', text: app_title('Sign in')) }
```

Output:

```
expected css "title" with text "CredSimple - Sign in" to return something
```

I would like to rspec to tell me what its encountering in addition to this message that its not able to pass the test. Is there a directive that I can use to tell the engine to output what page it is seeing?
Something like:

```
expected css "title" with text "CredSimple - Sign in" to return something **instead returned text "Wrong Page Title"**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this using `save_and_open_page` statement in the rspec. This creates an HTML dump that can be viewed in an editor or browser so that you can determine what's in the test's source.

To implement this I took the following steps

- Add   gem 'launchy' to Gemfile
- $ Bundle install
- insert save_and_open_page into the it { } block of the tests that I'm trying to debug
- placement is important:

  it { save_and_open_page should have_selector('div.alert') }